# CentOS Computer Name Resolution without Domain Name

Tags: networking, dns, centos

I have a network of CentOS6 machines.  Pretend the names are :

```
computer1.someDomain.net
computer2.someDomain.net
computer3.someDomain.net
```

From computer1.someDomain.net, I can run commands like "ssh computer1" or "ping computer2".  This behavior also works on computer2.  However, from computer3, "ping computer1" fails with a "ping: unknown host computer1".  I have to run "ping computer1.someDomain.net" to get this to work.

Stranger still -- on computer1, "nslookup computer3" returns the appropriate name and IP address.  However, on computer3, "nslookup computer3" returns SERVFAIL.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any differences in `/etc/resolv.conf`? E.g. different `search yourdomainnamehere.tld` parts?

Comment: That was it, missing a "search someDomain.net" in the /erc/resolv.conf file.  Post this as the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DNS resolver will usually try to resolve a name to an IP address.

By default, it will not try to add parts to the name. The exception is when you add a line to `/etc/resolv.conf` containing the search keyword. E.g. add `search mydomain.tld`.

In that case both the host and the host.mydomain.tld will be attempted.